# How to delete next character (not current!) in vim?

Tags: vim

I often find myself needing to delete the character after the cursor, but not the current character. What's the shortest way to do this in normal mode in vim?

Comment: Hope [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60627/vim-how-to-configure-backspace-and-delete-keys-both-as-normal) helps

Comment: looks like there's no one keystroke to do this...

Comment: Alex, not in the standard stuff but the mapping capability lets you set it up quite easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`lx` will do the trick, or `lxh` if you want to return your cursor to the original position.

It simply moves the cursor forward and deletes the character under it.

If that's not short enough, you can map it to a single keypress:

```
:map <f5> lxh
```

Then just use the <kbd>f5</kbd> function key.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are many ways to do that, there is another 3-strokes way:

```
xpX
```

note that, either `xpX` or `lxh` would fail if your cursor on the EOL. :)

Comment: What if we want to delete EOL ?

Comment: Better than accepted answer since it works for proper removal of the last character in the line (when caret located at the previous one) without changing caret position. To avoid overriding clipboard value one can use some custom buffer, e.g. `"0x"0p"_X`

Answer (score 1):

The shortest sequence that I know is also the obvious one:

Type "l x h" in command mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are commands to delete the character before the cursor Shift-X, but not after it. I tend to do lxh to get this done. . .